# View my own Join Date

Tags: support, dates

Where can I view my join date in my profile? At the moment, it says "member for 1 year", but I would like to see the exact date when I joined the site. Is this information available somewhere?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pretty much all time stamps on the sites, including that one, show you the precise (UTC) time in a tooltip when you hover over it with your mouse.

Comment: You're right, how could I miss that?